# Extremely strange Web-Scraping issue: Post request not behaving as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, mechanize

I'm attempting to programmatically submit some data to a form on our company's admin page rather than doing it by hand.

I've written numerous other tools which scrape this website and manipulate data. However, for some reason, this particular one is giving me a **ton** of trouble.

### Walking through with a browser:

Below are the pages I'm attempting to scrape and post data to. Note, that these pages usually show up in js shadowboxes, however, it functions fine with Javascript disabled, so I'm assuming that javascript is not an issue with regards to the scraper trouble.

*(Note, since this is a company page, I've filled I've replaced all the form fields with junk titles, so, for instance, the client numbers are completely made-up)*

*Also, being that it is a company page behind a username/password wall, I can't give out the website for testing, so I've attempted in inject as much detail as possible into this post!*

Main entry point is here:

[image]

From this page, I click `"Add New form"`, which opens this next page in a new tag (since javascript is disabled).

[image]

On this page, I fill out the small form, click submit, which then gets the next page displaying a success message.

[image]

Should be simple, right?

### Code attempt 1: Mechanize

```
import mechanize
import base64
import cookielib


br = mechanize.Browser()

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
br.addheaders.append(('Authorization', 
    'Basic %s' % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))))
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML,'
    ' like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22')]

br.open('www.our_company_page.com/adm/add_forms.php')

links = [link for link in br.links()]

# Follow "Add a form" Link
response = br.follow_link(links[0]) 

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form['formNumber'] = "FROM_PYTHON"
br.form['RevisionNumber'] = ['20']
br.form['FormType'] = ['H(num)']

response = br.submit()

print response.read() #Shows the exact same page! >:(
```

So, as you can see, I attempt to duplicate the steps that I would take in a browser. I load the initial `/adm/forms` page, follow the first link, which is `Add a Form`, and fill out the form, and click the `submit` button. But here's where it get screwy. The response that mechanize returns is the exact same page with the form. No error messages, no success messages, and when I manually check our admin page, no changes have been made.

### Inspecting Network Activity

Frustrated, I opened Chrome and watched the network tab as I manually filed out and submitted the form in the browser.

Upon submitting the form, this is the network activity:

[image]

Seems pretty straight forward to me. There's the `post`, and then a `get` for the css files, and another `get` for the jquery library. There's another `get` for some kind of image, but I have no idea what that is for.

#### Inspecting the details of the POST request:

[image]

After some Googling about scraping problems, I saw a suggestion that the server may be expecting a certain header, and the I should simply copy everything that gets made in the POST request and then slowly take away headers until I figure out which one was the important one. So I did just that, copied every bit of information in the Network tab and stuck in my post request.

### Code Attempt 2: Urllib

I had some trouble figuring out all of the header stuff with `Mechanize`, so I switched over to urllib2.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64 



url = 'www.our_company_page.com/adm/add_forms.php'
values = {
    'SID':'', #Hidden field
    'FormNumber':'FROM_PYTHON1030PM',
    'RevisionNumber':'5',
    'FormType':'H(num)',
    'fsubmit':'Save Page'
    }
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

headers = { 
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset' : 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent' :  'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)', 
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)),
    'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie' : 'ID=201399',
    'Host' : 'our_company_page.com',
    'Origin' : 'http://our_company_page.com',
    'Referer' : 'http://our_company_page.com/adm/add_form.php',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, ' 
            'like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31'
    }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

As you can see, I added header present in Chrome's Network tab to the POST request in `urllib2`.

One addition change from the Mechainze version is that I now access the `add_form.php` page directly by adding the relevant cookie to my Request.

However, even with duplication everything I can, I still have the exact same issue: The response is the exact same page I started on -- no errors, no success messages, no changes on the server, just returned to a blank form.

### Final Step: Desperation sits in, I install WireShark

Time to do some traffic sniffing. I'm determined to see WTF is going on in this magical post request!

I download, install, and fire up Wireshark. I filter for `http`, and then first submit the form manually in the browser, and then run my code with attempts to submit the form programmatically.

This is the network traffic:

### Browser:

[image]

### Python:

[image]

Aside from the headers being in a slightly different order (does that matter), they look exactly the same!

So that's where I am, completely confused as to why a `post` request, which is (as far as I can tell) nearly identical to the one made by the browser, isn't making any changes on the server.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this? Am I missing something obvious? What's going on here?

---

### Edit

As per Ric's suggestion, I replicated the `POST` data exactly. I copies it directly from the Network Source tab in Chrome.

Modified code looks as follows

```
data = 'SegmentID=&Segment=FROMPYTHON&SegmentPosition=1&SegmentContains=Sections&fsubmit=Save+Page'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

The only thing I changed was the `Segment` value from `FROMBROWSER` to `FROMPYTHON`.

Unfortunately, this still yields the same result. The response is the same page, I started from.

## Update

---

### working, but not solved

I checked out the `requests` library, duplicated my efforts using their API, and lo' magically it worked! The POST actually went through. The question remains: *why*!? I again took another snapshot with wireshark, and as near as I can tell it is exactly the same as the POST made from the browser.

### The Code

```
def post(eventID, name, pos, containsID):

    segmentContains = ["Sections", "Products"]
    url = 'http://my_site.com/adm/add_page.php'
    cookies = dict(EventID=str(eventID))
    payload = { "SegmentID" : "",
                "FormNumber" : name,
                "RevisionNumber" : str(pos),
                "FormType" : containsID,
                "fsubmit" : "Save Page"
            }

    r = requests.post(
            url, 
            auth=(auth.username, auth.password),
            allow_redirects=True,
            cookies=cookies,
            data=payload)
```

### Wireshark output

---

#### Requests

[image]

#### Browser

[image]

So, to summarize the current state of the question. It works, but I nothing has really changed. I have no idea why attempts with both Mechanize and urllib2 failed. What is going on that allows that `requests` POST to actually go through?

## Edit -- Wing Tang Wong suggestion:

At `Wing Tand Wongs` suggestion, I created a cookie handler, and attached that to the `urllib.opener`. So no more cookies are being send manually in the headers -- in fact, I don't assign anything at all now.

I first connect to the adm page with has the link to the form, rather than connecting to the form right away.

```
'http://my_web_page.com/adm/segments.php?&n=201399'
```

This gives the `ID` cookie to my `urllib` `cookieJar`. From this point I follow the link to the page that has the form, and then attempt to submit to it as usual.

#### Full Code:

```
url = 'http://my_web_page.com/adm/segments.php?&n=201399'
post_url = 'http://my_web_page.com/adm/add_page.php'
values = {
    'SegmentID':'',
    'Segment':'FROM_PYTHON1030PM',
    'SegmentPosition':'5',
    'SegmentContains':'Products',
    'fsubmit':'Save Page'
    }
username = auth.username
password = auth.password

headers = { 
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset' : 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent' :  'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)', 
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)),
    'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host' : 'mt_site.com',
    'Origin' : 'http://my_site.com',
    'Referer' : 'http://my_site.com/adm/add_page.php',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31'
    }

COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.lwp'
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

if os.path.isfile(COOKIEFILE):
    cj.load(COOKIEFILE)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)

req = urllib2.Request(post_url, data, headers)
handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print handle.info()
print handle.read()
print
if cj:
    print 'These are the cookies we have received so far :'
    for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
        print index, '  :  ', cookie
    cj.save(COOKIEFILE)
```

Same thing as before. No changes get made on the server. To verify that the cookies are indeed there, I print them to the console after submitting the form, which gives the output:

```
These are the cookies we have received so far :
<Cookie EventID=201399 for my_site.com/adm>
```

So, the cookie is there, and has been sent along side the request.. so still not sure what's going on.

Comment: It seems like you are posting to different URLs every time you automate it. Can you make sure you are posting to `add_form.php` and not `add_forms.php` when using `urllib`?

Comment: @Ric- Ah, That was a small typo in the post. I went through and quickly replaced all of the actual urls with placeholder ones. I got a few of them mixed up. However, the urls in the actual code are 100% correct. The best way to verify this is to check out the wireshark images I attached. I blanked out the host, but the rest of the url is visible, so you can see that they match on both.

Comment: Can you turn on PHP error reporting at the top of the add_page.php with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`?

Comment: @Ric Hmm.. Sorry, I'm not entire sure how to go about doing such a thing. Googling didn't yield useful results. Is that something I could be somehow accomplished with urllib?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for `add_page.php`?

Comment: @Ric Unfortunately, I do not. I'd have to track down whoever originally made our site, and ask that me modify the source. I'd lean towards him giving a "No" to that request. :(

Comment: Okay. I have answered with my best guess.

Comment: Instead of wireshark try proxying through fiddler or (my favorite) charles. They will let you compare the requests (the one your browser makes to the one mechanize makes) and easily add/remove headers or form vars until you figure out which one is the culprit.

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro: It may be useful to (packet) inspect the server replies for the different "clients". Compare the server response to `mechanize` with the response to `requests`.

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro Your 3rd screenshot has your real company URL. You may want to edit this out.

Comment: Can you compare what's the response of Requests , such as header and output, together with that of URLlib and mechanizer, that's likely to give you idea what went wrong.

Comment: @Winston I believe all of the headers are shown in the Wireshark snap shots in the post. As far as I can tell, they're exactly the same (though in a slightly different order). Is that the info you wanted to see, or do you want me to add a different snapshot or output of some kind?

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Usually you can see there what the server thought of your request, and whether there were any errors or anomalies (depending on the level of reporting it's set up for). Not sure if that is under your control, or whether you would have to rely on a friendly sysadmin to let you have a peek...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read and re-read your post and the other folks answers a few times. My thoughts:

When you implemented in mechanize and urllib2, it looks like the cookies were hard coded into the header response. This would most likely cause the form to kick you out.

When you switched to using the web broswer and using the python 'requests' library, the cookies and sessions handling was being taken care of behind the scenes.

I believe that if you change your code to take into account the cookie and session states, ie. presume an automated session at start, has an empty cookie for the site and no session data, but properly tracks and manages it during the session, it should work.

Simple copying and substituting the header data will not work, and a properly coded site should bounce you back to the beginning.

Without seeing the backend code for the website, the above is my observation. Cookies and Session data are the culprit.

Edit:

Found this link:  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Which describes accessing a site with authentication/etc. The format of the authentication is similar to the Requests implementation you are using. They link to a git source for a urllib2 implementation that does the same thing and I noticed that the authentication bits are different from how you are doing the auth bits:

https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705

from the page:

```
password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, gh_url, 'user', 'pass')

auth_manager = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_manager)
```

I wonder if you change the way you are implementing the authentication bits for the urllib2 implementation, that it would work.

Comment: I've updated the question to show my attempt at implementing your suggestion. Unfortunately no change in behavior.

Comment: Hmm... sorry to hear that. :( Without knowing how the underlying php page is handling stuff, kind hard to tell beyond that.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for giving this a shot. I know it was a bit of a long shot.

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro, did a little more looking into the python Requests module and found this little bit comparing a Requests implementation and then a urllib2 implementation. Updated my answer with the details.

Comment: Wha--!? Whoa! Holy molly! That did it!! All my bounty goes to you, my friend. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help. That was an interesting problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the PHP script is erroring out and not displaying anything because your form data is not exactly identical. Try replicating a post request to be completely identical including all the values. I see that the line-based text data on your Wireshark screenshot for the browser includes parameters such as SegmentPosition which is 0, but in your Python screenshot does not have a value for SegmentPosition. The format for some of the parameters such as Segment seem different between the Browser and the Python request which may be causing an error as it tries to parse it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but unfortunately still no luck. I've edited my question with updated code and results, but the summary is that I still get the same response.